# Error C1189 d3d10.h is included before d3d10_1.h

Tags: directx, components

aI'm trying to make a Component based 3d engine and I'm getting this error over and over again, here it is:

```
error C1189: #error :  d3d10.h is included before d3d10_1.h, and it will confuse tools that honor SAL annotations. If possibly targeting d3d10.1, include d3d10_1.h instead of d3d10.h, or ensure d3d10_1.h is included before d3d10.h  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft directx sdk (june 2010)\include\d3d10_1.h  75
```

I suspect (but not sure) this came out when I created this h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <D3DX10math.h>

typedef D3DXVECTOR2 Vector2;
typedef D3DXVECTOR3 Vector3;
typedef D3DXVECTOR4 Vector4;
typedef D3DXMATRIX Mat4;
```

And my d3dclass include part:

```
#include <Windows.h>

#include <D3D11.h>
#include <D3DX11.h>
#include <DXGI.h>
#include <D3Dcommon.h>
```

I'm using the directx SDK june 2010

Please help

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use D3DXMath, D3DX11, or the legacy DirectX SDK. See [this](http://aka.ms/dxsdk) post.

Comment: Thanks chuck! now i'm using the new d3dmath,it's ugliest than the previous one but no errors, also I modified the shader code with the new windows 8 sdk

Comment: You might want to check out [SimpleMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2013/01/08/simplemath-a-simplified-wrapper-for-directxmath.aspx) in the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929).